# how to show all the records using date-range i.e. From & To

Tags: c#, date-range

I can filter the data using `From` & `To` dates filter but it filters the data `in-between` those two dates rather than including `From` & `To` dates itself. i.e in the **[Screen Shot](http://s27.postimg.org/n2dwcs0n7/Capture.png)** as you can see, that it ignores the results from `From` & `To` and shows the data in-between. How can i get it to display `From` and `To` data aswell?

Here's my date filter controller code for your inspection:

```
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime toDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
        if (dateFilter.Contains('~'))
        {
            fromDate = dateFilter.Split('~')[0] == "" ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(dateFilter.Split('~')[0]);
            toDate = dateFilter.Split('~')[1] == "" ? DateTime.MaxValue : Convert.ToDateTime(dateFilter.Split('~')[1]);
        }

        filteredTracks = filteredTracks.Where(c => (trackFilter == "" || c.ArtistName.ToLower().Contains(trackFilter.ToLower()))
                                              &&
                                              (fromDate == DateTime.MinValue || fromDate < c.Date)
                                              &&
                                              (toDate == DateTime.MaxValue || c.Date < toDate)
        );
```

Any help would be great :) Thanks

Comment: Use <= and >= instead of < and > operators. Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6a71f45d.aspx for more reference on C# operators.

Comment: @Edin soo stupid of me.. don't know how I missed that. Thanks for your help and it resolved the query. How can I +rep you? thanks again :)

Comment: Posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *less than or equal to* `<=` and *greater than or equal to* `>=` relational operators.